# Cannot run my program

Tags: java, arrays, jcreator

Why I can't run this? It always say that the variable element cannot find? Help me please! Thank you so much!

This is the code:

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Work
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {

        InputStreamReader myInput = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader myBuff = new BufferedReader(myInput);

        int simpleArray[] = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19};

        for (int element = 0; element <10; element++);
        {
            System.out.println("Element #" + element + "holds the value" + simpleArray(element)+".\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: simpleArray[element], not simpleArray(element)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the `for` statement

```
for (int element = 0; element <10; element++); <-- here
```

`for` loops have a scope of their own. If you're putting a semicolon at the end of it, the scope ends. Since `element` has been defined within the loop's scope, it becomes invisible aftet the semicolon.

Comment: @Gendarme Not wanting extra reputation points for answers like these. It's not fairplay.

Comment: @Gendarme Making a community wiki post is a way to let others easily edit a post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki

Comment: Thank you! I can run it now but it doesn't show anything. It only shows Process Completed. What do you think is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @TiffanyLee Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
System.out.println("Element #" + element + "holds the value" + simpleArray(element) + ".\n");
```

is technically out of the for loop, so the variable element is not visible/ or is just out of scope **AND** this `simpleArray(element)` is not the way to get a element in an array... use `[]` instead

## QuickFix:

move that inside of the for loop  and use `[]` for getting elements on the array....

## Example:

```
int simpleArray[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 };

for (int element = 0; element < 10; element++) {
    System.out.println("Element #" + element + "holds the value" + simpleArray[element] + ".\n");
}
```